# Capture everything between a group of two special characters, but allow the character to appear once in the body

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to capture everything between `##` groups. In the following text "*this is the ##example## I am ##currently## testing on*", I would like to get the following matches: `example` and `currently`. I narrowed it down to this rule: `/##([^\#]+)##/g`. The rule has two drawbacks:

1. it returns the "custom boundaries" (i.e. `##example##`, not `example`) and
2. it doesn't work when there's a single `#` inside a "match" (i.e. `##ex#ample##`).

What do I need to change to make it work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just match any characters between the markers, and make it non-greedy by adding `?` after the quantifier `+`:

```
/##(.+?)##/g
```

The results of a match is the whole match in the first item followed by all the matched groups. As you have one group in the pattern you will have the content between the markers at index 1, i.e. `match[1]`

```js
var text = "this is the ##exa#mple## I am ##currently## testing on";
var re = /##(.+?)##/g;
var match;
while ((match = re.exec(text)) != null) {
  // show match in the Stackoverflow snippet
  document.write(match[1] + '<br>');
}
```

Note: the `.` in the pattern matches any non-linebreak character. You would use `[\W\w]` instead to allow linebreaks also.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your regex like below and get the string you want from group index 1.

```
##((?:(?!##).)+)##
```

`(?:(?!##).)+` would match any character but not of `##` one or more times.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jL2lG2/2)

```
> var s = "this is the ##exa#mple## I am ##current## testing on"
> var re = /##((?:(?!##).)+)##/g;
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(s)) != null) {
... console.log(m[1]);
... }
exa#mple
current
```

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. It was interesting to "debug" it. Unfortunately I am going to accept @Guffa's answer as I find  it easier to follow.

Comment: But Guffa's answer has some pitfalls.

Comment: Could you please expand on that?

Answer (score 0):

For your first flaw you need a capturing group which captures only your need  like   ##([^#]*)##   For your second flaw your need to make your regex non-greedy like ##([^#]*?)##
Now print the group(1)

Comment: @Guffa If the input has ##### then your regex will match #. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, just like `##ex#ample##` has a single `#` inside it, so does `#####`.

Comment: Not sure whether thats what he wants to capture. Anyway making the regex non-greedy is a good idea.

Comment: The operation with the original code is that it won't match if there is a hash character inside it, and I think that's what refered to as "doesn't work" for the second point, so the desired behaviour would be that it did match.

Comment: Agreed. Suggest me a way in which the regex matches null/empty string when the input is ##### and matches exa#mple if the input is ##exa#mple##. Thanks.

Comment: You could use `*` instead of `+` in the pattern to allow it to match the empty marker `####`. I can't find any mention of expecting `example` rather than `exa#mple`, but that could be solved by doing a replace on the result.